# using usercontrol in C# within the project

Tags: c#

I have a forms application and I do want a separate project for my one custom control that I need to use in 2 different places in my app.

I have have created a user control in the same project but I do not know how to use it in the program. It does not show up in the toolbox even if I drag it, it shows the drop cursor but then nothing happens. Will I have to use it manually ? or is there a better way.

Please help.

THanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **Tools -> Options**, under the section for "Windows Forms Designer", ensure that **AutoToolboxPopulate** is `True` - then the toolbox should automatically populate with all user controls from all projects in the current solution.

Comment: ...when you build the user control(s).